# Why is WebClient blocking in this web-flux app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm working on a web-flux app that exposes an http endpoint that makes a WebClient call, then modifies the response body of the WebClient call, and then returns to the client. When I enabled blockhound I found it was blocking and I'm trying to figure out why.

Below is the simplest version of code I could come up with to recreate the behavior. I also put a working project here: https://github.com/aztosca/web-client-test. The injected WebClient.Builder is Spring's pre-configured instance they recommend using.

I assume blockhound complains because an eventloop thread is blocked. I thought using WebClient would prevent this from happening and ensure any blocking happens on an appropriate thread, but something else is happening here I don't understand yet (i'm new to webflux).

Can someone help me understand why this is blocking on a thread it shouldn't block on? And suggest how to fix it?

- netty:       4.1.58
- spring-boot: 2.4.2
- spring:      5.3.3

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebClientTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockHound.install();
        SpringApplication.run(WebClientTestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    static String endpoint  =  "http://postman-echo.com/get?name=value";

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> testWebClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        
        WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
        
        HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> testHandler = new HandlerFunction<>() { 
            @Override
            public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {

                Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get().uri(endpoint)
                        .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(body -> Mono.just("Modify the response " + body));

                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                        .body(stringMono, String.class); 
            }
        };
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/test-web-client").and(
                accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)),testHandler::handle);  
    }
}
```

This is what happens when using `http://postman-echo.com/get?name=value` like in above code.

```
Caused by: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.parseEtcResolverSearchDomains(UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:373) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.parseEtcResolverSearchDomains(UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:354) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.<clinit>(DnsNameResolver.java:137) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:49) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at reactor.netty.transport.NameResolverProvider.newNameResolverGroup(NameResolverProvider.java:405) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    ......
```

This is what happens if you modify the endpoint to use https:  `https://postman-echo.com/get?name=value`

```
Caused by: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:388) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:331) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1993) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:365) ~[na:na]
    ......
```

Comment: it is probably blocking on reading `application.properties`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not that it matters, I don't think it's blocking on that. We can see UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider is in on stack trace. Docs for that class indicates it does i/o... 


_Able to parse files such as /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/resolver to respect the system default domain servers._


I just added the second stack trace which happens when using https. Looks like it blocks reading the truststore.

Comment: here is the reported issue https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10925 so updating to `netty-4.1.58.Final` will probably solve the issue

Comment: Thanks again. Somehow i missed this when searching around before posting my question here. I'm on 4.1.58 now, but based on this pull request it looks like it'll be in 4.1.59.Final: https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10935

Comment: latest seems to be 58 https://github.com/netty/netty/releases 59 is in the milestone repo https://github.com/netty/netty/milestone/234

Answer (score 0):

This seems to a reported [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10925).

A fix has been [merged](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10935) which will be released in version `4.1.59.Final` which as of time of writing has not yet been released, but is a planned [milestone](https://github.com/netty/netty/milestone/234).

Comment: I think you're on the right track. That merge instructs blockhound to ignore blocking calls invoked under the _parse_ method of netty's _UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider_ class. I tested this and it doesn't fix my issue. My stack traces shows different methods.

Being new to webflux my gut reaction is that my code is doing something wrong, but based on comments so far it seem like maybe blockhound needs to be configured properly. I'll keep digging on this. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: After some more digging [I posted an issue over on netty's github](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/11004).